# uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::FB Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am using ruby 1.9.3 Rails 3.2.13 for making an app that can post on facebook wall by using a dialog box (feed dialog)

In my view -

```
<%
FB.ui(
  {
   method: 'feed',
   name: 'The Facebook SDK for Javascript',
   caption: 'Bringing Facebook to the desktop and mobile web',
   description: (
      'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
      'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
      'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
   ),
   link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/',
   picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/public/f8.jpg'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) 
      alert('Post was published.')
     else 
      alert('Post was not published.')
    end
  }
);
%>
```

IN MY controller

```
def func
cache_expire = 1.year
response.headers["Pragma"] = "public"
response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=#{cache_expire.to_i}"
response.headers["Expires"] = (Time.now + cache_expire).strftime("%d %m %Y %H:%I:%S %Z")
render :layout => false, :inline => "<script src='//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>"
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

It is given this error on my view page -

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::FB
```

on FB.ui line..
please help I am new with this!

Comment: Whatever the "FB" class is, it's not available. Do you need to install a gem?

Comment: I have already installed 'xmpp4r_facebook' before and facebook javascript sdk doesn;t need any..where the FB method is to be difened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to mix Ruby and JavaScript in your view, but you only need JavaScript. Try removing the erb tags `<%` from your view and wrapping the JS in `<script>` tags.